# Как подружить JS с IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

ребятки!

Очень нужен Ваш совет - есть аккордион (Используется для фильтра на сайте). Аккордион появляется на дисплеях менее 780 px, в противном случае отображается только содержимое.

Проблема: IE не поддерживает шаблонные строки, а именно символ `

Помогите справиться с этой проблемой?

Спасибо.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 780) {
        document.getElementById('secondary').innerHTML = `<div class="accordion-filter">Фильтр</div><div class="panel-accordion"><?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?><?php is_active_sidebar( 'shop' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?><?php do_action( 'after_sidebar' ); ?></div>`
    } else {
        document.getElementById('secondary').innerHTML = `<?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?><?php is_active_sidebar( 'shop' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?><?php do_action( 'after_sidebar' ); ?>`
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пишите без шаблонных строк, с обычными кавычками и вкараплениями плюсов и имен переменных. PHP код не нужно заворачивать

Comment: В вашем примере, может даже лучше всю строку после знака равно заворачивать в <?php ?> и реализовывать логику и вывод полностью на php, а не мешать языки

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я очень плохо знаю PHP код. Попробую понаглеть и попросить Вас написать то, на что мне нужно заменить этот код))

Comment: Пробовал вставлять код через Babel, но почему-то это не помогает. Перестает работать во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

Вы завернули php в js, т.е. вы пытаетесь выполнить php в браузере, т.к. php - серверный язык, то он никогда не выполнится в браузере.
Самый простой путь - без js, просто в @media-запросах css измените поведение элементов.